# Why is there a private Object::select? Where are the public select methods coming from?

Tags: ruby

It was business as usual when I noticed this little gem:

> > nil.select
>
> NoMethodError: private method `select' called for nil:NilClass

Why does nil have a private `select` method?

I also noticed that `Array.methods` and `Enumerable.methods` has no `:select`, so where's their select coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is from `Kernel` module that is included in `Object` class. `NilClass` is parent of `Object` then include methods form `Object` and `Kernel`

[Kernel](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Kernel) module has select method.