# Private method select called for class - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller

I have the following code inside my controller:

`array = Contact.select(:name).distinct`

The idea is that this would create an array of all `Contact` models with a unique `:name` attribute. However, it's throwing this error:

`NoMethodError (private method 'select' called for Contact:Class)`

What's the misunderstanding here? For what it's worth, the method calling this line of code is not defined in the controller as private.

## EDIT:

Here's the actual code:

## Controller

```
class FluidsurveysController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def import_contacts
    @survey_provider = FluidsurveysProviders::SurveyProvider.new()

    @current_month = Time.new.strftime("%B%Y%d")

    fs_contact_list_array = csv_to_array(params[:file].tempfile)
    @fs_contacts_array = []

    fs_contact_list_array.each do |hash|
      @fs_contacts_array << Contact.new(hash)
    end

   array = Contact.select(:name).distinct
   end
end
```

## Model

```
class Contact
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_reader :client_id, :client_name, :branch_id, :branch, :short_name, :unit_id, :membership_id,
              :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :change_date_time, :membership_type,
              :home_phone, :email_address, :anniversary_years


  def initialize(fs_contact_hash = {})
    @client_id = fs_contact_hash.fetch('ClientID')
    @client_name = fs_contact_hash.fetch('ClientName')
    @branch_id = fs_contact_hash.fetch('branchID1')
    @branch = fs_contact_hash.fetch('branch')
    @name = fs_contact_hash.fetch('ShortName')
    @unit_id = fs_contact_hash.fetch('UnitID')
    @membership_id = fs_contact_hash.fetch('MemberID')
    @first_name = fs_contact_hash.fetch('FirstName')
    @last_name = fs_contact_hash.fetch('LastName')
    @date_of_birth = fs_contact_hash.fetch('DateOfBirth')
    @change_date_time = fs_contact_hash.fetch('ChangeDateTime')
    @membership_type = fs_contact_hash.fetch('MembershipType')
    @home_phone = fs_contact_hash.fetch('HomePhone')
    @email_address = fs_contact_hash.fetch('EMail1')
    @anniversary_years = fs_contact_hash.fetch('Years')
  end
end
```

Comment: FWIW: the Rails API reference states this exact usage as an example: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-distinct

Comment: You wrote "is not defined in the **controller** as private", did you mean **model** instead?

Comment: No, I mean the method itself is not a private method. However, none of my model attributes are private either.

Comment: Maybe try `Contact.all.select(:name)`

Comment: Is your Class an ActiveRecord Object?

Comment: I have edited the question to include more info.

Comment: Your class is not an ActiveRecord class, see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your error message I am pretty sure your model is not an ActiveRecord Object.

If you want to make use of `ActiveRecord#select`, define your model like this.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Also you need to define your attributes in a database instead of via attr_reader to access them through ActiveRecord. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#running-a-migration

Comment: If Arjan is correct, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585677/why-is-there-a-private-objectselect-where-are-the-public-select-methods-comin) might help explain the error further.

Comment: That does it...Thanks for the extra explanation, off to continue my learning.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be using an older version of Rails, specifically version 2.3.whatever. There, the `select` method is indeed private on the ActiveRecord model classes (as it is inherited from the `Kernel` module which is part of every Ruby object and serves a wholly different purpose)  and thus isn't intended to be used like it is done in Rails 3 and Rails 4.

In Rails 2.3, you can achieve similar results using this syntax:

```
Contact.all(:select => "DISTINCT name")
```

This will return an array of Contacts which have only the name attribute set.

Comment: @Luigi If you would have pasted the full stack trace of your error, this would have been clearer immediately.